# pthread_exit() throws warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] warning

Tags: c++, c, casting, type-conversion, pthread-exit

I have been learning about *pthread* library, and have created a simple code to multiply two numbers, however I'm not able to get rid of this warning.
Ps. The code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct numbers {
   int num1,num2;
};

void *mult(void *param) {
   struct numbers *data = param;
   int res = data->num1 * data->num2;
   pthread_exit((void *)res);
}

int main(){

   pthread_t tid;
   struct  numbers n;
   n.num1 = 2;
   n.num2 = 3;
   pthread_create(&tid, NULL,mult, (void*)&n);
   int res;
   pthread_join(tid, (void *)&res);
   printf("%d\n",(int)res);
   return 0;
}
```

Here's the warning:

```
1.c: In function ‘mult’:
1.c:12:17: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   12 |    pthread_exit((void *)res);
```

Any insights would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you include `<stdint.h>`, change res to be an `intptr_t`; it should shut up your  compiler.  Your compiler is just being a karen.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
pthread_exit((void *)res);
```

to

```
pthread_exit((void *)&res);
```

Comment: In the original posted code `res` is an auto; see the NOTES section for [pthread_exit()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html)

Comment: Don't do that, that is quite wrong.  If you are lucky your program will fault; but normally this just propagates invalid data.

Comment: @mevets is right about this. I have tried your solution before, it gets rid of the warning although provides us with a wrong answer.